# Что за юзер "nobody"

Tags: nginx

Объясните пожалуйста это:

Файл nginx.conf

```
user  nobody;
```

Что за юзер "nobody"? Какие еще есть и каких могу использовать?

Comment: https://nginx.org/ru/docs/ngx_core_module.html#user

Comment: Есть в unix системах такой пользователь. у которого мало прав. что бы ничего не сломали. а вообще все пользователи хранятся в /etc/passwd

Answer (score 1):

для работы многих демонов (в частности, обслуживающих какие-то сетевые запросы, например, http-серверов) не требуется никаких «особых» полномочий.

а ещё в коде таких демонов бывают ошибки, которые могут эксплуатироваться злоумышленниками.

а ещё такие демоны могут быть сконфигурированы вызывать интерпретаторы каких-нибудь скриптовых языков (php, python, и т.д. и т.п.), выполняя код, написанный владельцем машины (а чаще скачанный им из каких-нибудь «левых» источников, типа сайтов, распространяющих какие-нибудь cms и тому подобные кишащие ошибками и «бэкдорами» наборы скриптов).

учитывая вышеизложенное хорошим решением для пущей безопасности будет выполнение таких демонов от имени какого-нибудь «рядового» пользователя (лучше — даже не обладающего правами запуска интерактивных сеансов).

---

разработчики таких демонов для этого реализуют, например, следующую логику: как и все другие демоны, такой демон запускается пользователем root, а затем понижает свои привилегии (пользователю root это доступно), переключаясь на указанного (в конфигурационном файле) «рядового» пользователя.

вот такую конфигурацию вы и наблюдаете: программа nginx после запуска (и считывания файлов конфигурации, для чего нередко могут потребоваться полномочия root-а), переключается на работу от имени пользователя (в вашем случае) `nobody`.

ещё часто используется (как раз для работы http-серверов в debian-основных (да и во многих других) дистрибутивах) имя пользователя `www-data`.

---

посмотреть всех имеющихся в системе пользователей можно, например, командой

```
$ getent passwd
```

Comment: Понял спасибо большое!

Comment: Есть еше один вопрос. А можно указать других юзеров ?

Comment: И еще, щас у меня на конф файле (nginx.conf) этот юзер закомментирован. #user nobody... вот, когда я запускаю nginx, он под каким юзером запускается ?

Comment: [задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) (у вас их уже два, т.е. нажать на кнопку надо будет два раза)

Comment: задать вопрос (у вас их уже два, т.е. нажать на кнопку надо будет два раза) а причем тут кнопка "задать вопрос" ?

Comment: Я вас не понемаю...

Comment: комментарии не предназначены для задания и ответов на вопросы. чтобы задать новый вопрос, нажмите кнопку «задать вопрос» в правом верхнем углу страницы.